# Iterating object array within object - javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, iteration

I know iteration has been covered before - I'm usually pretty ok with it but struggling this time.

I have the following information I'm trying to loop through:

```
Object { leaving: object { all: array[10] } }
```

I can quite easily return a single result by returning:

```
 var html = '<p>' + news.leaving.all[0].departure_time + '</p>';
```

But when I try to loop:

```
    var html = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {                
        html +=
        '<p>' + news[i].leaving.all.departure_time '</p>';
     }
```

I get nothing…

Any help with this will be great.

Thanks

Comment: can you provide the array data?

Comment: Is `news` the Object you wrote at the top? What is its length property? (Clue: it looks to me like it doesn't have one.) Also you should consider using [forEach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10167931/5920499) for arrays.

Comment: news is not an array, news.leaving.all is. Question is a simple matter of typo, unlikely to be useful to future visitors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you need

```
'<p>' + news.leaving.all[i].departure_time '</p>';
```

rather than

```
 '<p>' + news[i].leaving.all.departure_time '</p>';
```

and change also

```
for (i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
```

to

```
for (i = 0; i < news.leaving.all.length; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks @ykay …  I tried that earlier but it didn't work either…

Comment: probably because yo uare looking at `new.length` which should also be switched

Answer (score 2):

You also have to iterate over the "all" member:

```
var html = "";
for (var i = 0; i < news.leaving.all.length; j++) {                
   html +=
   '<p>' + news.leaving.all[i].departure_time '</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the array `news.leaving.all`.

Code example:

```js
var news = {leaving: {all: [{departure_time: '01:00'},{departure_time: '02:00'},{departure_time: '03:00'}]}},
    html = "";
    
news.leaving.all.forEach(function (n) {
  html += '<p>' + n.departure_time + '</p>';
});

console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over `news.leaving.all`:

```js
// Let's say this is our data
var news = {
  leaving: {
    all: [{
      departure_time: '01:00'
    },
    {
      departure_time: '02:00'
    },
    {
      departure_time: '02:00'
    }]
  }
};

var html = "";
var i;
for (i = 0; i < news.leaving.all.length; i++) {                
  html += '<p>' + news.leaving.all[i].departure_time + '</p>';
 }
     
console.log(html);
```